# Pass the url as a parameter throw iis

Tags: asp.net, api, iis

I'm trying pass url as a parameter to asp web api controller
My controller endpoint looks like:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

Url i pass in this way:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/snapshot/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ru
```

But iis decode it and i have this:

```
http://localhost:2109/api/snapshot/http:/www.google.ru
```

Of course this url is incorrect and asp.net can't handle it

Anyone knows how turn IIS not to decodu urls?

Answer (score 0):

I try use query string and it works

```
http://localhost:3000/api/snapshot?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ru
```